# Keep Process From Context Switching

Tags: c++, windows, operating-system, scheduler

I have coded a specific process on Windows in C++ which continually polls to check if context switches have occurred. Because it is essential that this process not miss anything, I was wondering if there was a way of telling the scheduler to not context switch out this specific process while it is running. I am not simply talking about setting it to high priority, but setting it to a priority in which it is not switched at all.

Comment: So, you want  your process to starve and make unusable the entire OS if there's just one CPU in the system? Btw, it's impossible because despite thread priorities, Windows from time to time lets run the threads that haven't run for a long time.

Comment: It looks like you want to disable interrupts in user-mode. This is simply not possible, unless you write a custom driver and syscall to disable and enable as needed, which requires to learn how to write a Windows NT driver.